# Cardinality of a closed uncountable set.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am aware that every closed uncountable subset of reals has cardinality of the continuum.

It's easy to use this result to prove that the same is true in $\mathbb R ^n$, for each $n\in\omega$.

**Question.** What are some generalizations of this result? That is, are there general properties that a separable metric space can have, which guarantee every one of its closed uncountable subset has size of the continuum?

Comment: I think that's true for *Borel* sets in a *complete* separable metric space.

Comment: @bof that appears to be correct.  I found this "In particular, every uncountable Polish space has the cardinality of the continuum."

Answer (score 5):

This is too long for a comment, but: we could also ask about extending the "closed" side of the question. That is, in a "reasonable" metric space, what sort of sets do we know have the perfect set property? If this is interesting to you, you might be interested in *Descriptive Set Theory*!

For example, one result in descriptive set theory is that in any complete separable metric space (the underlying topological space of such a space is called Polish, by the way), every analytic set has the perfect set property. This is proved in Kechris' book, in the chapter "Games People Play" if I recall correctly. The analytic sets are a broad class of sets, properly extending the Borel sets.

Meanwhile, it is consistent with ZFC that *coanalytic* sets need not have this property! And in fact statements of the form "every set of type $\Gamma$ has the perfect set property" are closely related to *large cardinals* - roughly speaking, if we assume that the combinatorial structure of the set-theoretic universe is sufficiently rich, then every *projective* set has the perfect set property! (The projective sets are what you get by starting with the Borel sets and closing off under continuous image and complementation - that they extend the Borel sets properly was proved by Souslin, correcting an error of Lebesgue.) There are a pair of themes here:

- Regularity properties for sets of reals follow naturally from the *determinacy* of certain kinds of infinite games.
- Determinacy principles follow from, and in a certain sense imply (we have to be careful here - what I really mean is that they imply the existence of an *inner model* with large cardinals, or more coarsely the consistency of large cardinals with ZFC), large cardinals - which I'm not going to even try to sketch here, but see e.g. http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.ndjfl/1427202981.)

Descriptive set theory beyond the projective is studied, but I know very little about it.